# Given ${x^2-x y+y^2 = 15, x y+x+y = 13}$ find the value of $x^2+6y$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Both x and y are real numbers and x > y .
Given ${x^2-x y+y^2 = 15, x y+x+y = 13}$ find the value of $x^2+6y$ .
I tried solving the second equation to get $y=(13-x)/(x+1)$ and substituted that in equation one to get a quartic equation in x : $x^4+3 x^3-25 x^2-69 x+154 = 0$ .
I tried a few  rational root test guesses to no avail. Then I checked wolfram alpha to find out that it has no rational roots. So I think there must be a better way to compute $x^2+6y$ if x > y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

We have , $$x^2-xy+y^2+3(xy+x+y)=15+3\cdot13$$

$$\implies (x+y)^2+3(x+y)-54=0$$

Solve for $x+y$

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! Setting x+y=k and solving equation I get k=x+y=6 or -9 . What next ?

Comment: @AGoogler, my pleasure. So, we have $y=6-x$ or $-(x+9)$ Put the value of $y$ in the second equation to find $y$

Comment: Putting y=-9-x yields no real roots. Putting y=6-x in eq. 2 yields $x=3+\sqrt(2),y=3−\sqrt(2)$ ( since x>y) . Then $x^2+6y=29$ . Is this correct ? Also thanks again .

Comment: @AGoogler, We don't need the value of $x$. If $x+y=6,$ we have $x^2-6x+7=0$ and $x^2+6y=x^2+6(6-x)=x^2-6x+36=-7+36=29$

Comment: Wow ! That's a beautiful way to get the answer . You must be very good in math.

Answer (score 2):

Changing unknowns: $u=x+y, \ v=xy$ you get: 
$$
u^2-3v=15,\ \ \ u+v=13.
$$
From here
$$
u_1=6, \ \ v_1=7,
$$
$$
u_2=-9, \ \ v_2=22
$$
etc.